# Boolean theorems: Specific cases and inverter placement questions (3)

Tags: boolean-expression, circuit

1. If `D'=Z', then does D=Z?
2. Does (A+B)' = A' + B?
3. If an inverter is placed before the AND/OR then does it still act as a NOT/NAND?

Comment: this looks like a homework? you should be able to solve it by yourself, see [here](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/ee1_digital/Lecture4-Boolean%2520Algebra.pdf&sa=U&ei=MGjtUJTDE6an4ASp-YHYCA&ved=0CAcQFjAA&client=internal-uds-cse&usg=AFQjCNFUqmrvlI3bbjtpb3r65b3aycgGRQ)